# Eu tenho a seguinte query usando PDO,mas como faço para mudar para o Eloquent Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Isso serve para que eu informe através de um timestamp na coluna **data_remocao** caso o meu dado tenha alguma modificação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
foreach ($lista_cnae as $cnpj => $lista) {
                    $lista = "'" . implode("','", $lista) . "'";
                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE cnaes_secundarios SET data_remocao = now() WHERE cnpj=:cnpj AND cnae NOT IN($lista) AND data_remocao IS NULL");
                    $stmt->execute([
                        'cnpj' => $cnpj,


                    ]);

                }
```

Comment: Quais são os models que utilizará e o que a SQL faz?

Comment: Eu tenho uma tabela onde faço insert e update e caso a informação tenha alguma alteração como por exemplo um update eu informo para  minha coluna de remoção que aquele dado foi modificado através de um timestamp().

Comment: Se está utilizando o Eloquent, não bastaria criar os Models utilizando o *soft delete*?

Comment: Qual é a sua duvida? é fazer o `Model`?

Comment: A minha duvida e como criar essa query no Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 foreach ($lista_cnae as $cnpj => $lista) {
        //  $lista = "'" . implode("','", $lista) . "'";
        Cnaes::where('cnpj', $cnpj)
            ->whereNull('data_remocao')
            ->whereNotIn('cnae',$lista)->update([
                'data_remocao'=>Carbon::now()
            ]);
    }
```

Essa foi a solução para a minha duvida.

Comment: Então existia um Model...

Answer (score 1):

Use o Query Builder.

```
    \DB::table('cnaes_secundarios')
            ->where('cnpj', $cnpj)
            ->whereNotIn('cnae', $lista)
            ->whereNull('data_remocao')
            ->update('data_remocao', now()->toDateTimeString());
```